# Box change with number? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't understand how can I do it with jQuery.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="contentbox1" class="contentbox">content 1</div>
<div id="contentbox2" class="contentbox" style="display: none;">content 2</div>
<div id="contentbox3" class="contentbox" style="display: none;">content 3</div>
<div id="contentbox4" class="contentbox" style="display: none;">content 4</div>
<div id="contentbox5" class="contentbox" style="display: none;">content 5</div>
<hr />
<div id="pager" class="pager"> <span id="actualpage">1</span>/5</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.contentbox {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #cccccc;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
div.pager {
    cursor: pointer;
}
hr {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

I can't understand how can I develop it that if I click on `#pager` to see next box and change first number in `#actualpage`. Is it possible with jQuery functions?

I tried many ways to do it but without success. This is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/simplery/w8gcn/1/).

Comment: You have not included jQuery in your fiddle example. Checkout your JS console to see the errors.

Comment: Make sure you have included JQuery which is not there in your fiddle. Have a look at my answer for the same with **live demo**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8gcn/16/)

```
$("#pager").on("click", function () {
    var temp = $('#actualpage').html();
    $('#contentbox' + temp).attr('style', 'display: none;');
    temp = (parseInt(temp) + 1) % 6;
    temp = temp == 0 ? 1 : temp;
    $('#contentbox' + temp).removeAttr('style');
    $('#actualpage').html(temp);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle and it now works like a circular carousel. See if that helps and ask if you need to change anything.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/w8gcn/14/)

```
$("#pager").on("click", function () {
    var len = $('.contentbox').length;
    var cur = +($('#actualpage').text());
    if (cur === len) cur = 0;
    $('#actualpage').text(cur+1);
    $('.contentbox').hide();
    $('#contentbox' + (cur+1)).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that You have included JQuery in your page. 
Update your JQuery as mentioned below :

```
var currentPage = 1;
$("#pager").on("click", function () {
    var nextPage;
    if(currentPage == 5)
    {
        nextPage = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        nextPage = currentPage+1;
    }

    $('#contentbox' + currentPage).hide(500);
    $('#contentbox' + nextPage).show(500);
    currentPage = nextPage;
    $('#actualpage').html(currentPage);

});
```

1. <kbd>[Live demo with fading effect](http://jsfiddle.net/w8gcn/15/)</kbd>
2. <kbd>[Live demo with sliding effect](http://jsfiddle.net/w8gcn/24/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operator that changes the value of the variable count..simply

```
var count=1;
   $('#pager').click(function(){
       count++;
       $('.contentbox').hide();
       $('#contentbox'+(count)).show();
       $(this).find('#actualpage').html(count);
       if(count%5==0){count-=5};
   })
```